# How to filter WooCommerce page title?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, add-filter

I want to filter the shop page title by adding `<span>`-tags within the `<h1>`.
In the archive-product.php-file, the following code is present:

```
<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I don't really understand how I can use this filter. I could add `<span>` with a custom templatembut I want to know if this filter could be used instead. Or is it only for actually displaying the title?

When [looking into the actual function](http://hookr.io/functions/woocommerce_page_title/) `woocommerce_page_title` it does seem like it can be filtered:

```
$page_title = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_page_title', $page_title );
```

But when I add a filter to `woocommerce_page_title`, nothing happens. I have tried adding it with `add_action('plugins_loaded')` and `add_action('init')` but it doesn't work, for example:

```
function lcp_wc_filters() {

    add_filter('woocommerce_page_title',function($page_title) {
        return '<span>' . $page_title . '</span>';
    });
}

add_action('plugins_loaded','lcp_wc_filters');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked with the 'init'-hook:

```
function filter_woocommerce_page_title( $page_title ) {
    return '<span>'. $page_title . '</span>';
};

function lcp_wc_hooks() { 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'filter_woocommerce_show_page_title', 10, 2 );
}

add_action('init','lcp_wc_hooks');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
function filter_woocommerce_show_page_title( $array, $int ) { 
    return '<h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><span>'.implode(' ', $array).'</span></h1>';
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'filter_woocommerce_show_page_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This resulted in an error, "too few arguments". I tried removing the $int, but then I got "Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed".

Comment: When taking care of the errors it still didn't work. However I figured it out now, I think the 10, 2 integers did the trick!